# How to invoke DatePickerDialog *from a fragment* and return result

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

Many variations of this question have been asked and I've looked at answers until I'm glassy-eye'd, but I just don't see it. I have an app/activity that's handling schedules of several types and has invoked a fragment (I'll name cs2255) to deal with a particular type of schedule. Fragment cs2255 wants to obtain a date from the user and so, following guidelines and examples, in response to a button click, it has the following code:

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new StartDatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

The StartDatePickerFragment looks like:

```
public class StartDatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private DatePickedListener mCallBack;
    // Our host activity must implement this.
    public interface DatePickedListener {
        // we call with our return values
        public void onDatePicked(int aYear, int aMonth, int aDay);
    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int pYear, int pMonth, 
                         int pDay) {
        // What To Do Here???
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // Makes sure our container/host has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
        try {
            mCallback = (OnDatePickedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnDatePickedListener");
        }
    }
}
```

The answer examples that invoke the equivalent of StartDatePickerFragment from an activity are relatively simple and use bundles or callback interfaces to return the result but I'm not invoking directly from an activity so I don't think that works. The examples that invoke it from a fragment seem to all skirt the problem by storing or displaying the data locally without passing it back to the invoker. I don't want to move the date picker logic back to the base activity because it shouldn't need to know the details of the specific schedule or even if it needs to put up a date picker. But how can I accomplish the fragment to fragment communication with a reusable design?

I've added back in code segments that I've used in the past when the fragment was in fact hosted by an activity. I haven't actually tried this technique here because, the onAttach method receives an Activity argument (of the activity that initiated cs2255), but it's not the implementer of the interface. Fragment cs2255 would be the implementer and therefore I believe the ClassCastException will be thrown.

Comment: Edited listing above to remove interface definition left over from prior design attempt to use callback interface which I decided is only applicable when invoker is an activity.

Comment: Callback interface is one of the solutions here, so please put the code back and we'll see why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: I now normally use setTargetFragment and getTargetFragment for this and have cs2255 implement some interface that the DatePickerFragment can call to deliver the choice back.

Comment: I edited the original post as requested to add back in the code that I've used in different cases but believe will not work in this instance.

Comment: Thanks to David Mihola, I'm looking at set/getTargetFragment examples and that technique looks like it should work for fragment to fragment communication very well and analogously to the activity to fragment technique mentioned above. I'll post a new question if I run into problems, but I think this should work just fine. Thank you all for your time.